# Pre and post increment behaviour in C++

Tags: c++11

(C++) Why
`std::cout << ++(a++);`
shows `error: lvalue required as increment operand`
but
`std::cout << (++a)++;`
shows output "1"

(Java) But in Java in both the cases it throws exception. Cause increment and decrement operators work on variable not on values. And output of parentheses operator is always value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose because in the first case the code should do this: increment the value of what is after the ++ and then execute what is inside the parenthesis.

The problem is that the value after the ++ is not known, therefore you get the error.
This is only a supposition by the way, I hope some more skilled C++ dev can answer this, but if I have to suppose why you get the error I'll do this reasoning

Comment: Please learn about [*value categories*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). The result of the [postfix operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec#Built-in_postfix_operators) is an *prvalue* which can't be modified, while [the prefix operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec#Built-in_prefix_operators) returns an *lvalue*  which can be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of preincrement is `T&`, which allows you to modify it (because it's a non-`const` reference). Postincrement returns `T`: it's an unnamed value in the `t++` context. Therefore, the result is considered const-like so you can't change its state.

If you want to find more information, you can search up lvalues, (p)rvalues etc. but they might be hard to understand.

Comment: Is that "&T" or "T&"? Are you talking about reference of T?

Comment: `&T` is nonsense provided `T` is a type. If you mean `T` as an object (unlike I did), `&T` yields `decltype(T)*` pointing at `T`'s position in memory. Conventionally, `T` is a generic type. UPD: I meant `T&` as a reference to an object of the type `T`.

Comment: Ok thanks that clears a lot. I am accepting the answer. But it will be helpful if you can help me understand that why these two operators returns different type of values.

Comment: @RK_15 you can try implementing preincrement and postincrement. Preincrement is just `++(*this);` `return *this;` but postincrement requires copying `*this`, incrementing `*this` and `return`ing the copy afterwards (so it can't be a reference: the copy created during a function call is destroyed at the end of the scope).

Comment: OK so thats the way it returns the old value of the variable in case of post increment i.e. it is incrementing the value of the variable but returning the old value from the copied value of that variable. Thanks a lot buddy it really helped me a lot to understand a really simple concept.